# Hbase response size

Tags: memory-management, hbase

I have a bunch of rows on HBase which store varying sizes of data (0.5 MB to 120 MB). When the scanner cache is set to say 100, the response sometimes gets too large and the region server dies. I tried but couldn't find a solution. Can someone help me finding

1. What is the maximum response size that HBase supports?
2. Is there a way to limit the response size at the server so that the result will be limited to a particular value (answer to the first question) so that the result will be returned as soon as the limit is reached?
3. What happens if a single record exceeds this limit? There should be a way to increase it but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. What is the maximum response size that HBase supports?**

It is **Long.MAX_VALUE** and represented by the constant **DEFAULT_HBASE_CLIENT_SCANNER_MAX_RESULT_SIZE**

```
public static long DEFAULT_HBASE_CLIENT_SCANNER_MAX_RESULT_SIZE = Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

**2. Is there a way to limit the response size at the server so that the result will be limited to a particular value (answer to the first question) so that the result will be returned as soon as the limit is reached?**

You could make use of the property **hbase.client.scanner.max.result.size** to handle this. It allows us to set a **maximum size** rather than **count of rows** on what a scanner gets in one go. It is actually the **maximum number of bytes** returned when calling a scanner's next method.

**3. What happens if a single record exceeds this limit? There should be a way to increase it but I don't know how.**

**Complete record(row)** will be returned even if it exceeds the limit.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks much. This is helpful. I have another question - This seems to be a per-client setting. So I assume that the number of clients that are connecting the server at a given point can effect the limit and can get the server down (run it out of memory I suppose). How do people generally solve this problem and make their application robust?

Comment: Also, the response seems to skip results. For a batch size of say 100, if the limit is reached at 50 rows, the next 50 rows are silently ignored and not returned in the next batch. Am I doing something wrong.